# connect pgadmin3 to postgres runnng on server

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-18.04

** new to pgadmin and postgress **

my organization uses PostgreSQL on its server with ubuntu os, I try to connect it using      pgadmin 3,

these are the stapes I have taken

> > > changed pg_hba.conf using 'sudo nano /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf'
> > >
> > > changed listen_addresses='*'  in postgresql.conf file
> > >
> > > sudo ufw allow 5432/tcp

but still, I am unable to connect I get this error from pg admin:

Server doesn't listen
The server doesn't accept connections: the connection library reports could not connect to server: Connection timed out Is the server running on host "103.72.131.155" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

how can I fix it, 
is there any website which can guide me step by step to connect pgadmin to PostgreSQL.

Comment: Did you restart postgres after your config changes? Can you ssh into the server?

Comment: yes, I restarted using this command  " /etc/init.d/postgresql restart "